# How to have DataGrid Column Header Invisible if it Contains a Certain Value

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid`, is there anyway I can make a `DataGridColumnHeader` invisible if it contains a certain value.

Here is my attempt:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RunNumbers.RunNumbers}" >
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="rows">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
<DataGrid />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and define the columns that you want to display explicitly yourself, you can simply avoid setting the `Header` property of certain columns, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding RunNumbers.RunNumbers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- RunNumbers.Column1 has no header... -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Alternatively you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event in the view:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "rows")
        e.Column.Header = string.Empty;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding RunNumbers.RunNumbers}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

Comment: The `DataGrid` is bound to a `DataTable` so the columns are dynamic so this would work, thank you though

Comment: Do you want to show an empty header for all columns?

Comment: No just for the first column which has a name "rows"

Comment: @Alfie: Please see my edit. You could handle the AutoGeneratingColumn event.